# Access Indirect method for Excel

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
RSNonResourceCosts.Edit
RSNonResourceCosts.AddNew
RSNonResourceCosts![CostType] = Text1.Value
RSNonResourceCosts.Update


RSNonResourceCosts.Edit
RSNonResourceCosts.MoveFirst
RSNonResourceCosts![Header] = Text1.Value
RSNonResourceCosts.Update
```

Part of my Access program creates an Excel worksheet that uses the Indirect method.  I want the user to be able to add extra columns if necessary. The code necessitates adding the new column which is `Text1.text`. Then the last row of `[CostType]` should also be `Text1.text`. All that is fine, but the first row of the new column should also be `Text1.Text` (BUT field `[Header]` which is actually also `Text1.text` is not recognised.  Is there a method to fill this record automatically.  Thanks

Comment: AddNew adds new records, not "columns". The only method to fill a record field automatically is to set its `DefaultValue`.

Comment: The new field or "column" had already been added to the table.  I did not think that what I was asking could be done but I've just been programming for a couple of months so know diddly squat.  Sincerely, thank you.